# How to use json_decode in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
[{"Status":"FAILED","Message":"Trasaction Already Exist"}]
```

How to json_decode?

Currently using

```
$json=json_decode($response,true);
$status=$json["Status"];
$Message=$json["Message"];
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is an array, you need to go to index `0`. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` in the future to see what you have.

```
$json = json_decode('[{"Status":"FAILED","Message":"Trasaction Already Exist"}]', TRUE);
$status=$json[0]["Status"];
$Message=$json[0]["Message"];
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/94BmB